# How to get the Facebook Comments plugin working with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, facebook-comments

The problem is that I have the Facebook Comments plugin setup correctly, as far as I am concerned, but it's not displaying at all. Any opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's how I got it hooked up within my VueJS app, below.

The main index file:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<router-view></router-view>
```

The Vue instantiation:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: {},
  beforeMount: function () {

  },
  created: function() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : '****',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v3.1'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }
})
```

Container that is going to display the comments:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://tmp.local/dashboard#test/6" data-numposts="5"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
    name: 'cont',
    data () {
        return {

        }
    },
    mounted () {
        window.FB.XFBML.parse();
    },

}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: I'm no VueJS expert, but I don't think anything is calling window.fbAsyncInit. So the solution could be to remove that wrapper function and directly run FB.init instead.

Comment: fbAsyncInit does get called, I made sure. That anonymous Facebook function following fbAsyncInit most likely calls it, after it's finished loading.

Comment: not sure how FB-Comment work. But for your case, probably try ‘mounted(){this.$nextTick(()=>{window.FB.XFBML.parse()}}’.

Comment: @sphinx your add the nextTick hook worked for me.  Thanks!